# How to include featured image from the Wordpress website by sending push notification to mobile using OneSignal

Tags: php, android, wordpress, onesignal

I have a wordpress website. I can manage to send push notifications to its android app using OneSignal. For this, I made a Must-Use plugin in the wordpress website following this [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/wordpress#section-sending-notifications-only-to-mobile-apps-not-browsers-).

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to include the featured image from website inside the notification. Any help is needed.

Here is the code I used :

```
<?php
function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
        "myappurl" => $fields['url']
    );
    /* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to include featured image url in the data field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass thumbnail id and url in the data like this:

```
function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

$ImageId = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$ImageSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($ImageId);
$ImageUrl = $ImageSrc[0];

    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
        "myappurl" => $fields['url'],
        "thumbnail_id" => $ImageId,
        "thumbnail_url" => $ImageUrl,
    );
    /* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: I will try this to see.

Comment: Hi Ali, I have issue with this. here is my post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255275/onesignal-how-to-go-to-app-article-state-after-opening-notification-on-android